# In Cypress, how to check the headers of the most recent response?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, integration-testing, chai, cypress

In Cypress, I'm setting up my login loop, then want to extract certain headers for use in subsequent requests. Here's how I log in:

```
function login() {
  return cy.visit('/login')
    .get("#username").type(Cypress.env("USERNAME"))
    .get("#password").type(Cypress.env("PASSWORD"))
    .get("form").submit()
    .then((result) => {
      // TODO - extract the last response's headers and save for later
    });
}
```

But in that context, `result` is a DOM selection of the `form`, and I'm not sure how to get the most recent result.

Are there some interceptors or other way to submit a form that would give me more access to the request or response?

I can't just replace this with a `cy.request()` because it follows a few redirects to take me to a foreign SSO login page, hence why I need to only inspect the most recent result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I understand it, your form submit uses native `POST` request, not an XHR? If so then I'm not sure you can intercept that. Either way, chaining `.then()` on a DOM-based command won't ever yield a request object. You'll need `cy.route()` and `cy.wait()` for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the response from the url that contains your desired info. Look at this example.

```
cy.server().route('http://' + host + '/api/managerecord/userdetails/*').as('getUserDetails')
cy.get(submitButton).click()
cy.wait('@getUserDetails').then((response) => {
    expect(response.response.body.waistSize).to.eq(100)
})
```

In your case, put a route on that last respone and wait for that one. If you don't know that url have a look in the Chrome inspector.